# Laravel - using different id for unique validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm using `itemId` instead of `id` and when I validate as

```
'barcode'        => 'required|unique:item,barcode,' .$this->get('itemId'),
```

I get

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `item` where `barcode` = 5391510260790 and `id` <> 10)

How do I tell Laravel to use the `itemId` instead of `id` in the unique validation in the request class at the `authorize()` function?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the column to check using the fourth parameter to the rule:

```
'barcode' => 'required|unique:item,barcode,'.$this->get('itemId').',itemId',
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation it said, you must follow the following structure to tell which one is the id column.

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

You have to replace the idColumn with the name of the id column of yours. So the final code will be like this:

```
'barcode' => 'required|unique:item,barcode,' .$this->get('itemId').',itemId',
```